# Power plant systems: feedwater line or feed water line

Tags: compound-nouns

How do I have to write feed water line or feed water preheater?

"feedwater" as a single word or as two words "feed water"?

I have seen both versions in scientific publications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an engineer, I would use *feedwater* (one word). I am not entirely sure why, but I think it has to do partly with the fact that feedwater has a slightly more specific definition, not just "water that is being fed", but also involving thermal power cycles and other engineering specifics. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedwater_heater) appears to back me up on that.

Comment: Speaking as another engineer, I agree with you that "feedwater" is the correct term to use in this context.  But I would not rely on Wikipedia for validation of usage choices.  Wikipedia has incorrect usages for several scientific terms, and refuses to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

***Feedwater*** is not recognized by the Oxford English Dictionary.
But you can use it as a single word like how [Webster](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feedwater) has.

Comment: What would be more common or is there a general rule in English language? In German (which is my native language) all compound nouns are usually written as one single word.

Comment: Not a native speaker myself, but there is no consistent rule in hyphenating/using a space for compound nouns, as far as I know.
Let's see what our native speakers have got to say.